# Statute miles to runway visual range

Tags: flight-training, flight-instruments

Is there a formula to converting statute miles to runway visual range? If so, what would it be? I'm seeing how 1 mile is equal to 5000 feet, but I am so confused because 1/2 of a mile is equal to 2,400 feet. I would think 1/2 would be 2500 feet. If it was half of a mile, you would take 5000 and divide that by .5 or 1/2 to get 2500. (I'm not a pilot yet)

Comment: 1 statute mile is 5,280 feet, half of that is 2640. 1 nautical mile is 6076 feet, so I'm not sure where you are getting that half a mile is 2400 feet? RVR is usually already expressed in feet (or meters for our metric friends), I've never seen it shown in statute miles, mostly because RVR's over 6000' are not measured.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm seeing it online if I look up "SM co converted to RVR" but thanks, I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memorization.  This is the FAA definition:

```
Vis / RVR
1 SM / 5000
3/4 SM / 4000
1/2 SM / 2400
1/4 SM / 1600
```

This and a few more are spelled out in the Airman's Information Manual, TBL 5−4−1, RVR Value Conversions